# How to make Python 2's __getitem__ work on a class?

Tags: python, magic-methods, python-datamodel, first-class

How do I make item access ie. [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) available on a class object in Python 2.x?

I've tried:

```
class B:
    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls, key):
        raise IndexError
```

test:

```
B[0]
# TypeError: 'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
print B.__dict__
# { ... '__getitem__': <classmethod object at 0x024F5E70>}
```

**How do I make `__getitem__` work on the class itself?**

Comment: You'll have to put special methods on the *metaclass* instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've failed to find that question, thanks Martin. Although my `B` is an [old-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-old-style-classes), but the important thing here is the special methods I see.

Comment: old-style classes don't support `@classmethod` decorators (or any other descriptors) either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I made a mistake with that then. But I wonder, what happens with my decorator here? Whether my class is still old-style and whether the decorator gets ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369885/how-to-make-python-2s-getitem-work-on-a-class#comment35796553_23369885) by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), one would want to define a metaclass for the [special methods lookup](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) here.

If you can use new-style class (or don't know what's that):

```
class Meta_B(type):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        raise IndexError
#

class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta_B
#
```

test

```
B[0]
# IndexError, as expected
```